# ERROR: No matching distribution found for antlr4-python3-runtime==4.8 (Anaconda)

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have a question while creating a conda env using a yaml file.

The following error occurred while creating env using yaml file.

```bash
 Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement antlr4-python3-runtime==4.8 (from versions: 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.5, 4.5.2, 4.5.2.1, 4.5.3, 4.6, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8, 4.9, 4.9.1, 4.9.2, 4.9.3, 4.10, 4.11.0, 4.11.1, 4.12.0, 4.13.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for antlr4-python3-runtime==4.8

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

From what I've searched, it seems to mean that `antlr4-python3-runtime` version 4.8 is not available for download. But looking at the error, it seems to support version 4.8. So I wonder why it can't be installed.

Thank you.

Comment: you may want to check if you are installing using python2 or python3 i.e. try with pip3?

Comment: Can you share the yml file and also what OS you are on? Also share the complete error message above `Command errored out with exit status 1`. The output at the end is a bit confusing. It probably means that 4.8 was available for download and is compatible with your OS and python version, but during installation errored out and was tehrefore discarded. Therefore, it is interesting to see the rest of the output to determine what the actual error is